# Question about Egorov's Theorem

Tags: real-analysis

> Egorov's Theorem states that for a sequence of functions $f_n \to f$ pointwise on a subset $A \subset R$, $m(A)<\infty$, given $\epsilon>0$ there is a set $B \subset A$ such that $m(B)<\epsilon$ and $f_n \rightrightarrows f$ on $A-B$. Is it always true that given $\delta < \epsilon$ there is such a set $B_\delta$ such that $B_\delta \subset B_\epsilon$? If so, why? If not, what is a counterexample?

This is something I was thinking about today. My initial hunch (i.e. not at all formal) is that this statement is true; certainly it is for, say, $f_n(x)=x^n, f(x)=\chi_{\{1\}}$ on $[0,1]$. I have been trying to construct counterexamples in my head, but cannot. I think it underlies my lack of grasp about Egorov's Theorem - namely, why doesn't it say anything about the relationships between the sets $B_\epsilon$?

Comment: If you have uniform convergence on two disjoint sets, then you have uniform convergence on their union. We already have uniform convergence on $A-B_\epsilon$, and we still have pointwise convergence on $B_\epsilon$. Consider applying Egorov on $B_\epsilon$.